# Null pointer exception while trying to parse a json file

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to parse some information from a json file in android studio. I have followed a tutorial on how to do so, however I have run into a null pointer exception error while trying to fetch some information from the json file.

This is my parseJson function:

```
 private void parseJson() {
    String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/108hcz";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject person = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = person.getString("gender");
                    Log.e ("NAME:", name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mQueue.add(request);
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pogolemotoproektce/com.example.pogolemotoproektce.Activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
```

cause from this line:

```
mQueue.add(request);
```

My JSON file:
http://myjson.com/108hcz

What happens to be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mQueue` is not initialized that's why you getting null pointer exception so initialize `mQueue` before use.

```
 mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(your_context);
```

or you can directly call add with

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(your_context).add(request);
```

I have used like below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/108hcz";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject person = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = person.getString("gender");
                    Log.e("NAME:", name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
}
}
```

Comment: Yup that was the problem. It works now but for some reason it does not print the log the gender.

Comment: try to print your json above line ` try{`. and I suggest you always use optJSONArray(),optJSONObject() ,optString() because you can avoid json exception when parse

Comment: I debugged with page breaks and it doesn't even enter that part of the code at all.

Comment: is `onResponse()`  triggered?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Going to do a bit of research on why onResponse() might not trigger.

Comment: I put two logs. One in onResponse() and one in onErrorResponse(). Both of them do not log anything.

Comment: Where did you run it?

Comment: in android studio.. have you enabled internet permission?

Comment: post your activity or fragment code or post as new question

Comment: I have edited my code a bit but I will post the question. Also I am curious to know. What happens when you log the "name" object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042159/volley-onresponse-method-not-triggered this is the new question