# Volley onResponse method not triggered

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to parse a JSON file and fetch certain info from every person in the JSON file. I have created a parseJSON() function to do this for me, but I have run into a problem. The application works but it does not receive the information from the JSON file. After placing a breakpoint in the function, I realised that the application does not even acess the onResponse() function.

I have read the answers of some similar questions like this, but they did not seem to be of help.
What seems to be the cause of this?

parseJson() function:

```
private void parseJson() {

     JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject nameObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("name");
                    String title = nameObject.getString("title");
                    String firstName = nameObject.getString("first");
                    String lastName = nameObject.getString("last");
                    String email = jsonObject.getString("emial");

                    JSONObject prictureObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture");
                    String imageUrl = prictureObject.getString("medium");

                    String fullName = title + " " + firstName + " " + lastName;
                    Log.e("FULL NAME", fullName);

                    // Ignore this part
                    /*Book jsonBook = new Book(imageUrl, fullName, email, 50.0, 100, 3);
                    Books.add(jsonBook);*/


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(HomeActivity.this);

}
```

}

link to my json file: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ldql7

Comment: Your syntax is correct if the API is actually returning the response as a JSONArray, but you have to confirm this.  Set a breakpoint on the first instruction in the onResponse() method, then hover over the response object and check the data type.  As @MichaelStoddart said, more likely, it is coming in as a JSONObject with a JSONArray inside of it.  So, if the data type reads JSONObject, then his solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `JsonArrayRequest` when it needs to be a `JsonObjectRequest`. The body of your JSON file is contained within a Json Object:

```
{
    "results": [...]
}
```

Once you have changed the request type, modify your `parseJson` method like so:

```
 private void parseJson() {


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ldql7", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject nameObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("name");
                            String title = nameObject.getString("title");
                            String firstName = nameObject.getString("first");
                            String lastName = nameObject.getString("last");
                            String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

                            JSONObject prictureObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture");
                            String imageUrl = prictureObject.getString("medium");

                            String fullName = title + " " + firstName + " " + lastName;
                            Log.e("FULL NAME", fullName);

                            // Ignore this part
            /*Book jsonBook = new Book(imageUrl, fullName, email, 50.0, 100, 3);
            Books.add(jsonBook);*/

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }
            });



    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

Comment: I have given this idea some thought. But as I am new to Json I figured out that the json file is an array of users.

Comment: There is an error in the following line: 

JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");

getJSONArray
(int)
in JSONArray cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)

Comment: @VaskoVasilev yes the JSON is an array of users, but it is all contained within a single JSON object which is why you need to change the request type otherwise you will get an exception because the you are not getting the expected response type from the request. If you printStackTrace the error in onErrorResponse you will see what i mean

Comment: I changed the type of the request and the responcse. But this caused more errors to appear, mainly when I am trying to acess a subobject.

Comment: There is still an error in this line:
jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
getJSONObject
(java.lang.String)
in JSONObject cannot be applied
to
(int)

Comment: @VaskoVasilev change response.getJsonObject to array.getJsonObject

Comment: I just tried that, the whole code becomes erroneous.

Comment: There is still an error, the whole functions is underlined with red.

Comment: @VaskoVasilev as a developer you should be able to debug issues using common sense, the issue here is that the JsonObjectRequest does not have the correct parameters, see updated answer

Comment: Yeah, that was it. A new problem arose. repsonse.length()'s value is 2 even though there are 10 childer. Will see to this myself. Thank you.